# Glide custom adapter cannot access Fragment

Tags: android-recyclerview, adapter, android-glide

I'm trying to store the images on firebase storage and then retriving them and set into the recycler view. Using Glide I get this error, don't know how to fix it. Anyway If there is another way to retrieve and set image it's ok for me.

```
C:\Users\Gian\AndroidStudioProjects\RememberMe\app\src\main\java\com\example\rememberme\CustomAdapter.java:64: error: cannot access Fragment
            Glide.with(context).load(dataSet.get(listPosition).getAnime_image_url()).into(holder.image);
                 ^
      class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found
```

This is my onbindview:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        Glide.with(context).load(dataSet.get(listPosition).getAnime_image_url()).into(holder.image);
        holder.anime_eng_name.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getAnime_eng_name());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("toanimeelementfullbymainactivity", (Serializable) dataSet.get(listPosition));
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnimeElement.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved updating the Glide versione and Gradle.